# AutoMapper throws NullReferenceException with property named 'Original' in mapping source where destination is a record

Tags: automapper

I am getting `NullReferenceException`s in a mapping where the source type has a property named 'Original' and the destination of the mapping is a record (as opposed to a class). This is with AutoMapper version 12.0.1.

Based on Lucien's comment, I included calls to AssertConfigurationIsValid which indicated that the property was being mapped to a constructor parameter.

```
The following member on AutoMapperIssues.OriginalPropertyMappedToRecordIssue+TypedConstructorDestination cannot be mapped: 
    Void .ctor(TypedConstructorDestination), parameter original 
Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the destination type AutoMapperIssues.OriginalPropertyMappedToRecordIssue+TypedConstructorDestination.
Context:
    Mapping to member Void .ctor(TypedConstructorDestination), parameter original from AutoMapperIssues.OriginalPropertyMappedToRecordIssue+Source to AutoMapperIssues.OriginalPropertyMappedToRecordIssue+TypedConstructorDestination
Exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException' was thrown.
```

While investigating, I tried to define a record like this.

```
private record TypedPrimaryConstructorDestination(TypedPrimaryConstructorDestination Original);
```

This resulted in the following build error.

```
Error   CS8910  The primary constructor conflicts with the synthesized copy constructor.
```

The [documentation that covers the error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/constructor-errors#records-and-copy-constructors) includes the following text.

> Adding the record modifier to a struct or class type creates a record. Records include a compiler-synthesized copy constructor.

That links to further documentation that covers [non-destructive mutation of records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/constructor-errors#records-and-copy-constructors).

The following xUnit test class reproduces the issue and demonstrates the following workarounds. Make any one of these changes and the exception is no longer thrown.

1. Make the destination of the mapping a class instead of a record.
2. Use a name other than 'Original' for the property in the class that is the source of the mapping. Even 'Original1' works.
3. Map a null value which has been cast to the destination type to a constructor parameter named 'original'.
4. Changed the type of the Original property in the source to be the destination type.
5. Add a primary constructor with a single parameter with the same type as the source property.
6. Add a constructor with a single parameter with the same type as the source property.
7. Ignore non-public constructors.

```
using AutoMapper;

namespace AutoMapperIssues
{
    public class OriginalPropertyMappedToRecordIssue
    {
        [Fact]
        //This very specific scenario results in a NullReferenceException during mapping.
        //It also results in an AutoMapperConfigurationException exception when AssertConfigurationIsValid is called.
        //I posted on StackOverflow which is the first step in raising an AutoMapper GitHub issue.
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77316677/automapper-throws-nullreferenceexception-with-property-named-original-in-mappi
        //It looks like it is the automatically generated (synthesized) copy constructors in records that are at the core of this.
        //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/constructor-errors?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS8910)#records-and-copy-constructors
        public void Reproduction1()
        {
            Assert.Throws<AutoMapperConfigurationException>(() => TestSourceAndDestinationCombination<Source, Destination>());
        }

        [Fact]
        //Added a constructor with a single parameter named original typed as the destination.
        public void Reproduction2()
        {
            Assert.Throws<AutoMapperConfigurationException>(() => TestSourceAndDestinationCombination<Source, TypedConstructorDestination>());
        }

        private record TypedConstructorDestination
        {
            public TypedConstructorDestination(TypedConstructorDestination original)
            {
            }
        }

        //[Fact]
        //public void Reproduction3()
        //{
        //    TestSourceAndDestinationCombination<Source, TypedPrimaryConstructorDestination>();
        //}
        //private record TypedPrimaryConstructorDestination(TypedPrimaryConstructorDestination Original);

        private static void TestSourceAndDestinationCombination<TSource, TDestination>(bool shouldIgnoreNonPublicConstructors = false, Action<IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination>>? configure = null) where TSource : new()
        {
            var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(
                cfg =>
                {
                    var mappingExpression = cfg.CreateMap<TSource, TDestination>();

                    configure?.Invoke(mappingExpression);
                    cfg.ShouldUseConstructor = constructor => !shouldIgnoreNonPublicConstructors || constructor.IsPublic;
                }
            );

            mapperConfiguration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

            var mapper = mapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();

            var source = new TSource();

            mapper.Map<TDestination>(source);
        }

        private record Source { public bool Original { get; init; } }

        private record Destination;

        [Fact]
        //Changed the destination from a record to a class.
        public void Workaround1()
        {
            TestSourceAndDestinationCombination<Source, ClassDestination>();
        }

        private class ClassDestination { }

        [Fact]
        //Renamed the property named 'Original' in the source.
        public void Workaround2()
        {
            TestSourceAndDestinationCombination<RenamedPropertySource, Destination>();
        }

        private record RenamedPropertySource { public bool Original1 { get; init; } }

        [Fact]
        //Map a null value which has been cast to the destination type to a constructor parameter named 'original'.
        public void Workaround3()
        {
            TestSourceAndDestinationCombination<Source, Destination>(configure:
                expression => expression.ForCtorParam(
                    "original",
                    options => options.MapFrom(
                        source => (Destination?)null
                    )
                )
            );
        }

        [Fact]
        //Changed the type of the Original property in the source to be the destination type.
        public void Workaround4()
        {
            TestSourceAndDestinationCombination<PropertyTypedAsDestinationSource, Destination>();
        }

        private record PropertyTypedAsDestinationSource { public Destination Original { get; init; } }

        [Fact]
        //Added a primary constructor with a single parameter with the same type as the source property.
        public void Workaround5()
        {
            TestSourceAndDestinationCombination<Source, PrimaryConstructorDestination>();
        }

        private record PrimaryConstructorDestination(bool Original);

        [Fact]
        //Added a constructor with a single parameter with the same type as the source property.
        public void Workaround7()
        {
            TestSourceAndDestinationCombination<Source, ConstructorDestination>();
        }

        private record ConstructorDestination{
            ConstructorDestination(bool original)
            {
            }
        }

        [Fact]
        //Ignore any constructors that are not public.
        public void Workaround8()
        {
            TestSourceAndDestinationCombination<Source, Destination>(shouldIgnoreNonPublicConstructors: true);
        }
    }
}
```

This looks like a bug to me. The instructions in the [AutoMapper GitHub repository](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/new) ask for that to be confirmed here on StackOverflow before submitting it as an issue there. So please help to confirm that this is a bug.

> If you're new to AutoMapper, please ask a question on StackOverflow first and come back here if the people there consider it a bug.

Although there are a few workarounds, it will not be obvious to someone who gets a NullReferenceException, that the workarounds are available to them.

I think that AutoMapper should ignore 'copy constructors' by default. If I want to create a second instance of a record based on a first, then I can just use the copy constructor directly. There are a few workarounds here but there is no direct line to them from the NullReferenceException that developers will see first when they hit this issue. Records are still relatively new and usage is probably going to increase.

Comment: Call `AssertConfigurationIsValid`.

Comment: Thanks @LucianBargaoanu. For such a short comment, it got me much further along.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to use only public constructors:

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.ShouldUseConstructor = constructor => constructor.IsPublic);
```

Comment: Thanks! I added that to my tests and it works like you said.

Would you say that it is worth raising this as a GitHub issue for AutoMapper? For me, this started out as a NullReferenceException and it took quite some time to get this far.

It seems to me as if AutoMapper should always ignore these 'copy constructors'. If I want to create one record instance from another, then I can just use the constructor and don't need AutoMapper for that. It would save a lot of confusion, I think.

Comment: I don't think adding a condition inside AM for this case makes much sense, but you certainly do it in your own code.

Comment: OK. Thanks again for your help.